# MySQL 5.7.4 Startup Times Out

Tags: mysql, windows

I recently upgraded the MySQL Server installation on my Windows 8.1 Pro x64 laptop from 5.7.3 to 5.7.4 using the MySQL Installer, and after doing so, attempting to start the MySQL Server service, either using the MySQL Notifier or directly starting it from the services list fails. When the startup fails with the Notifier, it says that the attempted startup timed out, and suggests restarting the MySQL Notifier if the problem continues. I have tried that unsuccessfully and used IOBit uninstaller to uninstall everything on my computer related to MySQL (IOBit uninstaller scans the computer after uninstalling for leftover files. After uninstalling everything, I checked myself for leftover files and found none.). After reinstalling everything, I am still having the issue. What can I do to resolve the issue?

Here's what's generated in the error log when I try to start the server:

```
2014-04-24T01:06:11.128348Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-04-24T01:06:11.131351Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-04-24T01:06:11.132350Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-04-24T01:06:11.133350Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses system mutexes
2014-04-24T01:06:11.134350Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-04-24T01:06:11.134350Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2014-04-24T01:06:11.138350Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2014-04-24T01:06:11.139351Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-04-24T01:06:11.142350Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 26.0M, instances = 1
2014-04-24T01:06:11.145348Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-04-24T01:06:11.211309Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-04-24T01:06:15.902276Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2014-04-24T01:06:16.087552Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2014-04-24T01:06:16.930884Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2014-04-24T01:06:19.238141Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-04-24T01:06:19.242261Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-04-24T01:06:20.807291Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-04-24T01:06:20.869754Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.4 started; log sequence number 1232503
2014-04-24T01:06:20.872722Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.874714Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-04-24T01:06:20.876730Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2014-04-24T01:06:20.878731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.880729Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.882730Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.884720Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.886721Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.888731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.890730Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.892730Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.894716Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.896731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.898731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.900731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.902731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.905733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.907731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.909731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.910731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.913733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.915732Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.917732Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.919732Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.921734Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.923732Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.925733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.928718Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.930732Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.932733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.934718Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.936718Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.938733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.940733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.942733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-04-24T01:06:20.943756Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-04-24T01:06:20.945246Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-04-24T01:06:24.978930Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1232513
2014-04-24T01:06:24.983930Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2014-04-24T01:06:24.985946Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-04-24T01:06:24.987945Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-04-24T01:06:24.989945Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-04-24T01:06:24.990945Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-04-24T01:06:24.992944Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-04-24T01:06:24.994929Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-04-24T01:06:24.996944Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-04-24T01:06:24.997944Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-04-24T01:06:25.000468Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-04-24T01:06:25.002470Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-04-24T01:06:25.004954Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: `[ERROR] unknown variable 'innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M'`

Comment: @GhostGambler That's my problem right there. Why is the variable unknown and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

If you take a look at [the manual concerning `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_additional_mem_pool_size) you see that this is a configuration variable, which is relevant in combination with `innodb_use_sys_malloc`. If you take a look at [the manual concerning `innodb_use_sys_malloc`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_use_sys_malloc) you see that also this configuration variable was marked as deprecated and removed. If you follow the links further to [the detailed explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-performance.html#innodb-performance-use_sys_malloc) you can read:

> When InnoDB was developed, the memory allocators supplied with
>   operating systems and run-time libraries were often lacking in
>   performance and scalability. [...]
>
> Today, as multi-core systems have become more widely available, and as
>   operating systems have matured, significant improvements have been
>   made in the memory allocators provided with operating systems. New
>   memory allocators perform better and are more scalable than they were
>   in the past. [...]
>
> You can control whether InnoDB uses its own memory allocator or an
>   allocator of the operating system, by setting the value of the system
>   configuration parameter innodb_use_sys_malloc in the MySQL option file
>   [...]. If set to ON or 1 (the default), InnoDB uses the malloc and
>   free functions of the underlying system rather than manage memory
>   pools itself. [...]

Which basically means that this was a configuration variable which makes just no sense to set anymore in modern environments. Therefore it was deprecated and removed and also the `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size`, which just existed in support of the own memory management.

## Fix

Fix for your problem: Remove the corresponding line with `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size` and (if it even exists) the line with `innodb_use_sys_malloc` from your `my.cnf`.

Comment: I once again reinstalled everything and use MySQL installer, but the configuration failed because it said it couldn't connect to the database. Now the server can start up, but it does not list the example tables that I know I installed.

Comment: This cannot be solved in the comments. If you encountered a new error, you should start a new question and include new updated information.

Comment: No need to post a new question. I figured it out.